# Not well formed text in TextView after append()

Tags: android, string, textview, append

I am in trouble with my TextViews. I have not seen this problem before and Google didn't help.
I have TextViews and text, which defined in xml like string resources.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TVName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textViewTextSize"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marginBetweenTextViewsEnd"
        android:background="@color/gray41"
        />
...
```

In my code I am doing append() for this TextView

```
public class Page extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView TVName;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        TVName = findViewById(R.id.TVName);
        TVName.append(" " + "danya");
}
}
```

string.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="name">Name:</string>
</resources>
```

Instead of `NAME: danya` I am getting some hieroglyphs or just a trash like "NAME: 3ô"

First of all I was getting text for `append()` from server with Retrofit and think that this is malformed text from server, but problem has repeat when I tried code above.

When I changing append on `setText()` - everything works fine.

Also I have tried to change string resource in xml on text like `android:text="Name:"` but same problem.

All files encoded in UTF-8 as always and were not encoded manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much better solution will be to have string like this in your `string.xml`:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="name">Name: %s</string>
</resources>
```

And then, instead of setting that string in xml, just set it programmatically:

```java
TVName = findViewById(R.id.TVName);
String formattedName = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.name), "danya");
TVName.setText(formattedName);
```

Here's a good explanation of `String::format` and all the arguments that you can use to pass different data formats: https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples

Comment: Found solution and tried your code `String STVName = String.format(TVName.getText().toString(), " ", "danya");` and have got just `Name:` - why?

Comment: You shouldn't put a space as a parameter, because it's already in your string resource. `%s` in `R.string.name` represents an argument (which is `"danya"`). There's a space in the string already `Name: %s` :)
All you need to do - is just write `String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.name), "danya");`

Comment: and you are right, everything works. thanks for a good advice.

Comment: @danyapd here's an article about String.format and how it works: https://mobikul.com/string-placeholders-formatting-strings-android/ Hope it'll help you to understand it better :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to delete textAllCaps attribute and... it works. I think append didn't work with textAllCaps.
But I need caps in my code, so my solution is:

```
String getSTVName = TVName.getText().toString();
String STVName = String.format(getSTVName, "danya");
TVName.setText(STVName);
```